# schema.path is not a function for autoincrement

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I'm trying to add a auto-increment id field for a person collection in mongo cloud db, but I get `const schemaKey = this._schema.path(this._options.inc_field);` as an error at the line where I've put `const AutoIncrement = AutoIncrementFactory(conn2);`. The code is as follows:

**EDIT:**
Now the error is gone, but the auto-increment still doesnt work as expected, i.e. the `id` field is not auto-generated when saving a new person

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose);

if (process.argv.length<3) {
  console.log('give password as argument')
  process.exit(1)
}

const password = process.argv[2]

const url =
  `mongodb+srv://user:${password}@phonebook.plvo5px.mongodb.net/phonebookApp?retryWrites=true&w=majority`


mongoose.set('strictQuery',false)
mongoose.connect(url)


const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  
  name: String,
  number: String,
  personId : {
    type : Number
  }
});

const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema)
personSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement, {inc_field: 'personId'});




const person = new Person({
  name: `test2`,
  number: `0717323171`
})

person.save().then(result => {
  console.log('person saved!')
  mongoose.connection.close()
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [readme](https://github.com/ramiel/mongoose-sequence#readme) shows 2 different ways to include that module:

- When using a single connection to the database initialize with the mongoose object:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose);
```

- When using multiple connections to the database, initialize for each connection:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const AutoIncrementFactory = require('mongoose-sequence');

const connection = await mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://...');

const AutoIncrement = AutoIncrementFactory(connection);
```

The code you have is combination of the two, pick only one way.

Comment: Uh, sorry about that, I was not aware. Thank you, edited now. However, even with the edited code, the autoincrement does not generate the id field when saving new persons